# Possible to enqueue scripts and CSS to Multisite Network dashboard?

Tags: multisite, wp-enqueue-script, dashboard, network-admin

Is it possible to enqueue scripts and css **only** to the Network Admin Dashboard?

To edit the network admin menu, you have this hook: `network_admin_menu`, so I also tried `network_admin_enqueue_scripts`, but this didn't work.

Thanks!
Roc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the global variable `$current_screen`. It has the property `is_network`, with a boolean value, that indicates if we are in `/wp-admin/network/` or not.

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'network_scripts_wpse_91699' );

function network_scripts_wpse_91699() 
{
    global $current_screen;
    if( !$current_screen->is_network )
        return;

    wp_register_script( 'test', plugins_url( 'test.js', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test' );
}
```

This action hook can also be used like

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-site-new.php', 'callback' );`
```

and it will only print in the screen `/wp-admin/network/site-new.php`, so there's no need to check if the current screen is a network one or not.

Comment: Thank You. Just quickly tried w/ your suggestion, and it works perfectly!